# How can I get the way of java process started?

Tags: java

A Java process can be start by the 2 ways blew?

```
1. java -jar jarName.jar
2. java -classpath "lib/de.jar" com.Program
```

Can I find out how `Program` was started?

I want to distinguish between these two ways.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to care about that, though.

Comment: I'm not sure the `MANIFEST.MF` is used when importing a jar in the classpath, maybe that could be a track.